# Oracle bulk copy duplicate rows

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle11g

i have a datatabase table as follows:

```
id    min    max
---------------------
1      0     20
2      21    30
3      31    40
```

I am showing this table in grid view (asp.net) where user can insert new rows, update existing and delete any rows. This all manipulation I am storing in datatable.
After updating, inserting, deleting records, when user wished to save it, he or she pressed save button and this modified datatable is saved in database (the same table from where I filled grid view). To update database I am using `OracleBulkCopy` class. 
Now the problem is when I am updating datatable to database it is repeating rows which already exist. For example if I made changes to above table in grid view and updated it into database then:

```
id    min    max
------------------
1     0      20 
2     21     30
3     31     40
1     0      20 
2     21     35 (updated)
3     31     40  
4     41     60 (newly inserted)
```

I don't want this repetition. Here `id` is the primary key
and I tried following code for `OracleBulkCopy`:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy oracleBulkCopy = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy(DM.ConnectionString, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction);
oracleBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "RANGE";
oracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OracleBulkCopy` acts a bit like `SQL*Loader`. It does not care about duplicates and just inserts everything. In fact, it will disable your indexes before starting before enabling them again afterwards. See, for example, [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7287/5116) question. The workaround for this is for you to bulk copy into a temporary table with the same columns as your destination table then perform an `INSERT` into your table from this as this will allow you to ignore the duplicates.

EDIT: As per APC this will not scale too well. However, do look further into `WriteToServer`: you don't have to copy the entire datatable, you can copy based upon the `DataRowState`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm#BIGIBCDA). So, you could bulk copy only those that are new rows and, perhaps, perform the workaround for the modified rows. If you are allowing deletes from your datatable then you'll have to handle them separately too.

Comment: This "workaround" might suffice for homework but it really isn't  appropriate for a real application, one where performance matters.

Comment: @APC What would you suggest?